# How to get a table entities as a batches in Microsoft Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I would like to fetch a table entities from a cloud storage using Microsoft Azure Table Storage. And, it takes too long to fetch a large amount of data such as a 100000 entities. Is there any way to get entities as a batches with the count of 1000?

Thanks in Advance,

Paul

Answer (score 1):

TableQuery can pull records for queries in batches of 1000.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition

However Table Storage was designed to pull records by either partition key or row key.  If you have any other filter it will be slow as there are no indexes to help, so it has to pull each row and see if it meets your filter.  So I would loop through your partition keys and pull data that way.

After each batch of 1000, you get a continuation token to go get the next batch for that that query.  I have had some luck with setting up a blocking collection and data flow so I can kick off the next query and let that I/O happen while I am still processing the first query.